# Top Questions of the Week #2

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 2 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each we week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Comment: Suggestion with the questions of the week: at some point, `#1`, `#2`, etc. becomes less useful... when we get to question `#76`, who's going to remember where we're even counting from? I think it would place the questions in a more relevant context to say "Top Question for Week of Jan. 17, 2011" or something to that effect.

Comment: Does it really matter though? As long as we actually decide on picking one consistently and keep it up for 76 weeks in a row!

Comment: @Ivo, I suppose so. Perhaps both? `Top Questions of the Week #2 (Jan. 17, 2011)`

Comment: @nhinkle I would simply add the date somewhere in the body, it would make the title a bit long and it doesn't look as pretty!

Comment: @Ivo, fair enough, I suppose that works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I propose this question asked by our very own sys admin Kyle Brandt

### [How do I diagnose not being able to reach a specific website as an end user?](https://superuser.com/q/231977/1548)

This question was asked because some users were tweeting Jeff that they couldn't connect to Stack Overflow lately. To help them, Jeff created a nice CW answer that can help users troubleshoot reaching a site they can't reach, hosted on a site they probably can't reach when they can't reach the site they want to reach...

Case in point: I couldn't log into chat.SU this morning, but luckily I could still reach this question!

I did some troubleshooting, following all the steps laid out in the answer. Turns out my default DNS settings sucked:

[image][image]

So this question just predicted the future by solving a problem I didn't even knew I had!
I used the DNS benchmark tool from the question and picked two new DNS addresses. I even changed them on my router so all my devices get to benefit from it. So clearly, this question already deserves my QotW vote on monday!

Answer (score 4):

We're lucky this week, since there's more great content!

[**Does email address obfuscation actually work?**](https://superuser.com/q/235937/1548)

Asking whether it actually helps to reduce unwanted spam when sharing your email addresses in an obfuscated fashion such as:

> jt.superuser[AT]gmail[DOT]com
>
> **quixote** dot **su** over yonder near that **gmail** place

User Akira gives a great empirical answer:

[image: The Stats as it was made by Silvan Mühlemann]

**So yes, it does work!**

Comment: "Yes, (in a way) email obsfucation works." :)

Answer (score 1):

[This questio](https://superuser.com/questions/69050/how-to-change-the-windows-7-boot-screen)n is a great one for a how-to Style to customize your PC... great for the Super User Community:

> I want to change Windows 7's boot screen. Is there any way?