# 2011 Moderator Elections - Town Hall Chat: 3pm UTC on the 31st

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Monday the 31st at 3pm UTC, or 10am EST.**

[**click here to join**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/236/super-user-election-town-hall-chat)

([**view in other timezones**](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=1&day=31&year=2011&hour=15&min=0&sec=0&p1=0))

---

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match.  I believe we'll have all but one or two candidates joining us.  <s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase, so I am looking at the 29th-31st.  As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates, I will edit this post with details on the "when".</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=superuser.com).  You can register for the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/236/super-user-election-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule).
- **You must have 20 rep on Super User to speak in the chat room.**
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: If the time's good, I'll definitely be there.

Comment: Anything users or nominees can do to prepare?

Comment: @Rebecca, this could help: http://www.doodle.com/

Comment: @Benjol, doodle.com doesn't exactly have a user-friendly interface.  I did look at several similar web apps.  They all have something lacking.

Comment: @IvoFlipse, not really other than come with questions or if you're a candidate, be ready to answer/discuss. (:

Comment: Well technically speaking you must have at least 20 reps on *any* SE sites to be able to speak in the chatrooms, no?

Comment: I should be able to be there although it's during my working day so I'll be subjected to the demands of the corporate user base and network infrastructure.

Comment: I will be there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who participated, particularly the candidates! Virtual coffee is on me!

The full transcript to the Town Hall Chat can be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/236).

Whether you were able to attend or are just reading the transcript now, I hope this helps get to know the candidates before you vote. (:

---

A digest summary of the chat is available http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/438413#438413

Answer (score 5):

The only danger with this is that it could look bad for a candidate if the timing meant they couldn't attend - if it was in the middle of their work day for example.

Comment: Maybe best scheduled on a weekend - but we'll have to see who works weekends too! I'll be there unless circumstances dictate otherwise.

Comment: rebecca is working on scheduling software to provide a best fit

Answer (score 1):

If only half the candidates (can) show up, you could try to plan a second event for the others...